# Docker container doesn't update when file changes are made on host

Tags: docker

I'm using a docker image as my `dev` environment for a specific version of PHP. I am using PHP for a command line script so every time I make a change to the script I would like it to automatically make changes in the container.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I assumed it was. I mostly use `docker-compose` and I can add `VOLUMES` easily to achieve this, but not in this instance with docker.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY ./app /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENTRYPOINT [ "php" ]
CMD [ "./index.php" ]
```

I first run:

```
docker build -t app .
```

And then

```
docker run app
```

Everything works well. But if I change something in `index.php` I have to run the steps again. Is this expected behaviour or is there any way to have docker watch for changes?

Answer (score 2):

`docker run -v /home/user/location:/usr/src/app app`

Use a volume so that the files within the container reflect local changes.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

Comment: Is there any way to define the volume in the dockerfile?

Comment: No, Dockerfiles intrinsically can't refer to or require any specific host resources.

Comment: Had to remove as accepted as this didn't work. If I made any changes to `index.php` I still have to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a file using vim/sublime outside docker in your host, this is normal, because vim/sublime does not simple "edit" that file, but create a new file. see : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793

solution:

```
After some googling, Sublime text has atomic_save instead so Adding "atomic_save": false to user preferences worked (After a restart).
```

if you are using docker-compose, use this command:

```
$ docker-compose run --build
```